# MAX(ID) in SQL Server 2005 returning unexpected results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2005 database with a table an ID column. When I select MAX(ID), I get only 99, but the table contains ID no's from 0 to 103. It should select 103 as max, but it returns 99. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Please post the full query and your (partial) table schema. You're obviously limiting this somehow and we don't have all of the facts.

Answer (score 4):

Is `ID` numeric? Because if not, `'99'` as a string is "higher" or bigger than `'103'`.

Post the schema and the query.

Comment: This is most likely the issue happening. You can use MAX(CAST(ID as int)) to test it.